# Finding cross product with limited variables

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I'm trying to solve a problem involving cross product but I'm stuck on how to proceed.

The problem states, Assume $u$ x $w$ = $\begin{bmatrix}6\\-5\\7\end{bmatrix}$

then find:

$(5u - 3w)$ x $w =$ ?

I've been looking at properties of the cross product but still am confused as to how I proceed from here. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Distribute everything around, use the fact that $w \times w = \mathbf{0}$, etc...

Comment: I suppose that it is $u\times w$ not $u \times v$. Right?

Comment: if w x w = 0, does 3w x w do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [algebraic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties) of the cross product we have:

$$
(5u-3w)\times w=(5u)\times w -(3w)\times w=5(u\times w)-3(w \times w)
$$

and, since the self cross product is null:
$$
(5u-3w)\times w=5(u\times w)=[30,-25,35]^T
$$

Comment: How did you turn (5u)×w−(3w)×w into 5(u×w)−3(w×w)?

Comment: Read the link in my answer: the cross product is ''compatible with scalar multiplication''. The proof is simple from the definition.